# Tracing the size of my file in my AIR app + tracing size of my server file?

Tags: android, air, filesize, filereference

I've got an xml file in my AIR app and I'm trying to determine his size. Here's what I did :

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("horaires3.xml");
trace(file.url); //path to the file
trace(file.size);
```

But I've got this error : `Error #3003: File or directory does not exist.`

The `file.url` is working, but the `file.size` is throwing the error..

**2nd question (related) :**

Can I check the size of a file in my server with AS3 code ?

Would it be something as simple as :

```
var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mywebsite/my_xml.xml");
trace(myURL.size);
```

What I want to do is :

```
If (file.size == myURL.size){
//do nothing
}
else{
downloadmyURL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#exists)

> Indicates whether the referenced file or directory exists. The value is true if the File object points to an existing file or directory, false otherwise.

Adjust your code like this:

```
if (file.exists) {
    trace(file.size); 
} else {
    trace("File does not exist (yet!)");
}
```